# dhcp: lease expiration vs. infinite lease

Tags: networking, dhcp

As per RFC2131, when the lease expires the client has to stop using the IP address. So do I understand right that if the lease lifetime is set to infinite on the server, then the client does not need to renew/rebind its IP, and thus the server does not have to provide these timeouts (option 58 and 59) to client?